# Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback in Echelon B3

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-5.5, preg-replace-callback

```
    function removeColorCode($text) {
      return preg_replace('/\\^([0-9])/ie', '', $text);
    }
```

The above code gives a deprecation warning on Echelon B3 i think after upgrading to PHP 5.5.29 by our host provider

---

#### How can I replace the code properly with preg_replace_callback()?

Comment: @Toto I have seen that post but i didn't know how to correct my code

if you know please share it.............. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, just remove the `/e` it does nothing here.
You can also remove the `/i`
So your code becomes:

```
function removeColorCode($text) {
  return preg_replace('/\^[0-9]/', '', $text);
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me

Comment: @Rodlake: You're welcome, glad it helps.